# Can Druids tame a dinosaur?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, druid

In D&D 3.5, the rule book says nothing about a Druid being able to tame or have a velociraptor. Could a Druid tame one and use it as his/her companion?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Yes, a Druid can have a dinosaur as an animal companion, but with some limitations according to the rules-as-written. A higher-level Druid has more options than just the basic list, as described in the [alternative animal companions list](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#alternativeAnimalCompanions). Starting at level 7, a Druid can choose a deinonychus as an animal companion.

But wait, you say, I'm asking about a velociraptor!

Yes, well, there's a funny story behind what we call "velociraptor." A "velociraptor" as they're popularly known is actually *deinonychus*. The movie *Jurassic Park* called them "velociraptor" because it's a cooler name, and people have been mixing them up ever since. *Velociraptor* was actually very small—about the size of a chicken—and not nearly as impressive as *deinonychus*.

This point is important, because D&D 3.5e calls them by their correct name, "deinonychus". And that precise dinosaur is a rules-as-written legal animal companion choice for a Druid of level 7 or greater. (Other dinosaurs are also on the list at higher levels.)

The caveat here is that the base companion starts out more powerful, so it gets a level penalty in its animal-companion benefits: you count as 6 levels lower for calculating your deinonychus' companion stats, feats, etc.

Comment: What I love about paleontology is that for a study of things dead for millions of years, it's a surprisingly dynamic and changing field. Every decade or so they discover everything we knew is wrong and redefine everything. Fun!

Comment: @lisardggY I still miss poor *brontosaurus*. But the feathered T-Rex significantly makes up for that.

Comment: wait... WHAT HAPPENED TO BRONTOSAURUS?!?

Comment: Yes, I know the difference between them, and I usually just call it velociraptor just because its easier to spell, and I have a lisp making deinonychus sound awful. And brontosaurus was proven to have already been discovered as apatosaurus.

Comment: This answer blew my mind.

Comment: @ZeDemonPyro Yeah, I prefer calling it "velociraptor" in most contexts, because cooler and people know what I mean. The point about name is just that "velociraptor-as-we-know-it" is conveniently right there in the list, but you have to look under "deinonychus" to find it.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I feel bad about triceratops, being that scientists are questioning if it was even its own species, or just a juvenile torosaurus...

Comment: I say, give the Druid a velociraptor as requested.... "I roll 15, a hit", "ok, your 'raptor runs up and gives your target's ankle a nasty nip"..  that'll teach them to think movies are any substitute for learning.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, dinosaurs are animals and a number of them appear as options for the druid’s Animal Companion, particularly in the *Player’s Handbook*, *Monster Manual III* (which has a dinosaur skull on the cover), and the *Eberron Campaign Setting* (in Eberron, dinosaurs roam the Talenta Plains and many species are domesticated by the halflings who live there).

Options for a “raptor-like” dinosaur Animal Companions:

- 1st-level druids can have a [**leaellynasaura**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaellynasaura), which the Talenta halflings refer to as a **fastieth**. *Eberron Campaign Setting*
- 1st-level druids can also have the fictional **swindlespitter**, which is apparently a combination of the [**oviraptor**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oviraptor), which it looks and acts like, and *Jurassic Park*’s inaccurate portrayal of the [**dilophosaurus**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilophosaurus), since it spits venom as that one did. *Monster Manual III*
- 4th-level druids can have an actual **velociraptor**, which the Talenta halflings refer to as a **clawfoot**. Note that the velociraptor was quite a lot smaller than most people imagine; *Jurassic Park* got it wrong. See deinonychus, below, as well as SevenSidedDie’s excellent answer. *Eberron Campaign Setting*
- 4th-level druids can also have the fictional **fleshraker**, which is called exactly that in Talenta. Frequently banned, as the fleshraker makes far and away the most powerful creature available as an Animal Companion (many attacks, Pounce, and a nasty poison on every attack). *Monster Manual III*
- 7th-level druids can have a **deinonychus**, which is what most people *mean* when they *say* velociraptor since the *Jurassic Park* “velociraptors” were actually deinonychus; the Talenta halflings call that one a **carver**. [*Player’s Handbook*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#alternativeAnimalCompanions) + [*Monster Manual*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dinosaur.htm#deinonychus)
- 10th-level druids can have a **megaraptor**, which the Talenta halflings call a **great carver**. [*Player’s Handbook*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/classes/druid.htm#alternativeAnimalCompanions) + [*Monster Manual*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dinosaur.htm#megaraptor)

Also worth noting that all dinosaurs have the Animal type, which means Handle Animal and Wild Empathy also work on them.